# Can't bind to 'owlDateTimeTrigger' since it isn't a known property of 'span'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using the `OwlDateTimeModule` in my `smart-table-datepicker`. I have imported it in my `smart-table-datepicker.module`. I have followed some answers but it is still showing error. What am I doing wrong?

**smart-table-datepicker.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SmartTableDatepickerComponent, SmartTableDatepickerRenderComponent } from './smart-table-datepicker.component';
import { OwlDateTimeModule, OwlNativeDateTimeModule } from 'ng-pick-datetime';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [SmartTableDatepickerComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    OwlDateTimeModule,
    OwlNativeDateTimeModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    SmartTableDatepickerRenderComponent,
    SmartTableDatepickerComponent
  ]
})
export class SmartTableDatepickerModule { }
```

**smart-table-datepicker.component.html**

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt" class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
    <input
        [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt" [owlDateTime]="dt"
        [(ngModel)]="inputModel"
        placeholder="{{placeholder}}"
        [min]='min' [max]='max'
        readonly
        class="form-control">
</div>
<owl-date-time #dt [stepMinute]="15" [hour12Timer]='true' (afterPickerClosed)="onChange()"></owl-date-time>
```

Comment: If you import this module into another module you have to  add them to `exports`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are imported in your module `SmartTableDatepickerModule`, however, you have not imported `import { OwlDateTimeModule, OwlNativeDateTimeModule } from 'ng-pick-datetime';` into your component:

your-component.ts

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
.............
import { OwlDateTimeModule, OwlNativeDateTimeModule } from 'ng-pick-datetime';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@component({
selector: 'fooComponent',
templateUrl: 'your-component.html',
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class YourComponent{

public dateTime: Date;
}
```

UPDATE:

If this module is used in other modules, then you need to give a way to use their code into other libraries. So just export them:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [SmartTableDatepickerComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    OwlDateTimeModule,
    OwlNativeDateTimeModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    SmartTableDatepickerRenderComponent,
    SmartTableDatepickerComponent,
    OwlDateTimeModule,
    OwlNativeDateTimeModule,
  ]
})
export class SmartTableDatepickerModule { }
```

Comment: `OwlDateTimeModule` and `OwlNativeDateTimeModule` is not being used in my component.ts.

Comment: @Deep if you are using `OwlDateTimeModule` and `OwlNativeDateTimeModule ` in other modules, then you need to export them. Please, see my updated answer.

Comment: I have added. Not working. `OwlDateTimeModule`  and `OwlNativeDateTimeModule` is being used only in the .html file

Comment: @Deep just restart your application with `ng serve`

Comment: some suggestion in the erorr looks like this:

Comment: 1. If 'owl-date-time' is an Angular component and it has 'stepMinute' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'owl-date-time' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

Comment: @Deep could you create a Stackblitz example?

Comment: @Deep try to reinstall using this instruction [ngpick-datetime](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-pick-datetime)